# In win10 , why the lastest Parameters can't be using "&" in CreateProcess()?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

there is my code:

```
int main()
{
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
PPROCESS_INFORMATION pi;  
TCHAR szCommandLine[] = TEXT("C:\Windows\notepad.exe");
auto is_suc = CreateProcess(NULL, szCommandLine, NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);
return 0;
}
```

Is exist some problem in win10 CreateProcess() API ?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to compile the code?

Comment: Are you saying this fails to compile or is it just the intellisense giving a false warning

Comment: It fails to compile as he probably has a typo in his `pi` variable definition; should be `PROCESS_INFORMATION pi`, but he has `PPROCESS_INFORMATION pi` (note the initial `P`, which makes `pi` a `PROCESS_INFORMATION*`).

Comment: Please replace the image with the code in text form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Thank for reminding me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

> ```
> PPROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
> ```

This means (note that you have a **P** before `PROCESS_INFORMATION`, making the actual type a *pointer to* `PROCESS_INFORMATION`):

```
// PPROCESS_INFORMATION = PROCESS_INFORMATION*
PROCESS_INFORMATION *pi;
```

`CreateProcess` expects a *pointer to* `PROCESS_INFORMATION` as last parameter, but with `&pi` you are passing a **pointer to pointer** (double indirection).

You can fix that by changing the definition of your `pi` variable:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
```

Then `&pi` will correctly be a `PROCESS_INFORMATION*`, as `CreateProcess` expects. And, on success, the `pi` variable will receive the process identification information as expected.

**P.S.** For better code hygiene, I would suggest to clear the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure as well:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi{ 0 };
```

Comment: Adding pointers in typenames prepended by a P must be the worst convention ever.

Comment: @rubenvb: I tend to agree with you, that having explicit `*` can be better, as this example shows.

Comment: @rubenvb: The important thing about conventions is, that they are applied consistently. This one is. And since you obviously missed the reason, why there is a `typedef` for a pointer, don't forget that this is a C API